# Ubuntu Live CD hangs on boot

Tags: 11.10, installation, 11.04, boot, live-cd

I have burned 11.04 to a CD to set up dual-boot. But the Ubuntu screen just stays with the dots below the name and nothing else. I would really like to try it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You should try downloading and testing with either ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10. Every new version fixes bugs and problems, so it is quite likely that the problem you've run into is fixed in a newer version of Ubuntu.

Try ubuntu 12.04 LTS If you are looking for long-term support (for servers, corporate environment, etc), or ubuntu 12.10 if you are looking for a more up-to-date version going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu takes a lot of time to load from a live-CD and you may have guessed why.. cos its booting from a CD.

I would like to suggest : put Ubuntu on a pen-drive and try it from that.

I will be faster and you will have the ability to create files save them ... Install apps.. etc..

This software will be helpful : [UNetBootIn software for making pen-drive bootable](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want test the Ubuntu in LiveCD, try this:
Burn another disc or switch the cd reader device of your computer. Some cd readers maybe don't work for that test.
I already see this bug in my pc. That's work for my case.